# Syntax error near "elseif" Javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I have recently started having a need to start learning Java Script. My application is MVC 3, VB.NET. In one of my views I have the following snippet of javascript that simply looks at the clientName from a SignalR message and decides on the correct color to display that message based on if the string contains a certain string. The code snippet is as follow:

```
   chat.addMessage = function (myClientName, message) {
        if (myClientName.indexOf("System") != -1) {
        $('#messages').append('<br><b style="color:red">'+ myClientName + message + '</b>');
        }

        elseif (myClientName.indexOf("devloper") != -1) {
        $('#messages').append('<br><b style="color:Blue">'+ myClientName + message + '</b>');
        }
        else
        {
        $('#messages').append('<br>' + myClientName + ' : ' + message);
                    }

        if (autoScroll) {
            $('#messages').animate({ scrollTop: $('#messages').prop('scrollHeight') })
        }
    };
```

The problem is the elseIf line is not liking the french brace on the end... its saying I need a ";" I guess I could do away with the elseIf and just use an if but seems lame way to work around the issue...

Comment: Lolz wow! so many answers all saying the same thing! how will you choose?

Comment: Lols dunno... I up voted the first 4 that I got...

Comment: I was actually going to close the post right when I found it in a google search.. But figured i would leave it open for someone else who makes the same fail mistake I did...

Comment: it's those minute syntactical details that exist in one language but not another (PHP) !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use

```
} else if ( /*... */ ) {
```

instead of the single-word "elseif"

Answer (score 3):

It should not be `elseif` it should be `else if` So your code becomes

```
else if (myClientName.indexOf("devloper") != -1) {
```

Answer (score 2):

It's `else if`, separated with a space, not `elseif`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `elseif` in JavaScript. Instead you should use `else if`